# how to extract recent data and delete previous data if more column have same value

Tags: python, pandas

[input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvtpC.png)(input data have duplicates with some columns ,wants to delete previous data)

[output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A80zF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your input and output I think you want to remove duplicate rows:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df_output = df_input.drop_duplicates(cols, keep='last')
```

You'll have to specify which columns to use, I'm not sure from your example which columns define duplicates